# Jade, 3 elements under parent don't produce expected result

Tags: pug

I have this Jade template:

```
  .widget
    p
      h1 Title!
      | {#Price}:
      a(href='#{item.href}') Link
```

which produces:

```
   <div class="widget">
   <p></p><h1>Title</h1>$174 :
   <a href="#">Link</a>
   <p></p>
   </div>
```

I expected the logical structure:

```
   <div>
     <p>
       <h1></h1>
       <a></a>
     </p>
   </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It produces exactly what you where expecting. It's just invalid HTML and your browser turns it into sth. valid.

Answer (score 1):

That structure is probably what Jade produces as output, but in HTML, it’s not valid to nest an `<h1>` (a block element) under a `<p>` (which is only allowed to contain inline elements). Since HTML5 is not strictly XML, ending tags for some elements are implicit, including `<p>`, so the `<p>` element ends there. The browser then sees an extra `</p>` and creates another `<p>` element, because HTML parsing isn’t strict – but that part is invalid HTML.

Consider a `<div>` or something instead.

Answer (score 0):

There will be like this as follows::

```
.widget
    p
        h1
          | Title!
          | {#Price}:
        a(href='#{item.href}') Link
```

I think this will work and you will get expected results.